# How to select unique records in PostgreSQL without using Distinct clause

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a query which selects number of records for each house.

```
SELECT
   -- 3 rows
   a.house,
   -- 12 rows (for each house)
   a.id,
   -- for each ID (there are 4 repeating records)
   -- out of these 4 records, only 1 is unique while remaining are 
   -- repeated records
   a.points
FROM records a
group by a.house
order by a.house, a.id
```

Above query returns 144 rows (Here it is how: 4 repeatation for each number in ID column thus 12 IDs of one house returns 48, so 48 x 3 = 144 rows) . The third column contains 4 records (for each number in ID column) in which there is only 1 unique point for each house just like ID of the house. Thus, the output should give 12 (IDs and points) x 3 (houses) = 36 rows. The desired sample output would be:

```
house rows points
1      1    1
1      2    2
1      3    3
1      4    4
1      5    5
1      6    6
1      7    7
1      8    8
1      9    9
1      10   10
1      11   11
1      12   12
2      1    1
2      2    2
2      3    3
2      4    4
2      5    5
2      6    6
2      7    7
2      8    8
2      9    9
2      10   10
2      11   11
2      12   12
```

How can I remove these repeating records from third column without using PostgreSQL Distinct clause?

Comment: What about adding the second and third columns to the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I want to repeat the process for large number of houses (column1) that's why only grouping by column1.

Comment: Are the following assumptions about the original table correct? [1] The original table has 144 rows and 3 columns (house, id, points). [2] Column "house" contains 36 times the integer 1, 36 times the integer 2, 36 times the integer 3. [3] Columns "id" and "points" contain 12 x 1, 12 x 2 etc, up to 12 x 12. [4] The table does not contain NULLs.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :-) What I find confusing: the comments in the original question's SELECT - 3 rows / 12 rows / 144 rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Also, I was asking whether "the table has 144 rows" (not "the column").

Comment: I just corrected the details. My bad!.

Comment: @JibranKhan May I ask you to have a look at this "fiddle"? If I have understood correctly, your table resembles the "jkrecords".  Underneath, you find a query that may be of help.  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=153f74fe9667f4ae5e806e9e5be1020d

Comment: Yes, the table "jkrecords" show the scenario as exactly I just updated. Please see edit. My edit already reflects your "jkrecords" table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query that may get the "desired output" could look something like this:
(as @joanolo had suggested: adding the second and third column to the GROUP BY)

```
select
  R.house
, R.id rows_
, R.points
from jkrecords R
group by R.house, R.id, R.points
order by R.house, R.id;
```

See a worked example [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=153f74fe9667f4ae5e806e9e5be1020d).
Apologies to everyone, and to @a_horse_with_no_name in particular, for any confusion I may have caused with my "assumptions".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Instead, apologies from my side for posting a confusing question :)

Comment: We got there in the end :-) Best of luck!